# Using modulo in Swift strings - how do you capitalise every other letter?

Tags: string, swift, replace, character, modulo

I am looking to capitalise every other letter in a string in a Swift app. In javascript I would use the following:

```
var word = "hello world"

word = word.replace(/[A-z]/g, function(c, i) {
    return i % 2 === 0 ?
      c.toUpperCase() :
      c;
    });
```

Returns:

```
"HeLlO WoRlD"
```

How would you implement this in Swift?

A big thanks in advance, I have scoured the web for an answer and can't find one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to transform one letter on two to upper case, this should do the trick :

```
var str = "Hello playground"
var newStr = ""

for (index, char) in enumerate(str) {
    var s = "\(char)"
    if index%2 == 0 {
        newStr += s.uppercaseString
    } else {
        newStr += s
    }
}

println(newStr)
```

Demo : http://swiftstub.com/394531161/

*However, if you are looking to upper case on specific ranges only you might want to look for the `replaceRange` method.*

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I'm actually running that loop repeatedly each time and edit is made to the text field. If you do this it concatenates the `newStr` variable. So you can quickly clear the variable after use to prevent this. Thanks!